# Problem with shinyapps.io and Microsoft R Client - "rsconnect package out of date"

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps, revoscaler

I'm running RStudio 1.3 and Microsoft R Client 3.5.2 (to give me access to the `revoScaleR` package) on a Windows 10 PC. I'm now trying to set myself up to share Shiny apps using `shinyapps.io` so that I can - in future - send various "widgets" to clients remotely.

I've followed the instructions on the `shinyapps.io` website to install the rsconnect package in RStudio. The package installed ok. However I was then instructed to run the following code to authorise the account:

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                          token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                          secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

(obviously I've hidden the details of name/token/secret)

And I had an error message:

> Error: HTTP 426 GET https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/users/current/ The
>   rsconnect package is out of date.  Please update to the latest
>   available on CRAN.

Is this happening because by using Microsoft R Client 3.5.2 (instead of R 4.0.0 for example), I'm not able to access the very latest version of the package? If so, is there any way around this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: "Please update to the latest available on CRAN"

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this by downloading a `tar.gz` file from CRAN and installing it manually. This gives the latest version (0.8.16) instead of the version I previously had (0.8.13).